# Delete file from local commit. Can't use ammend option

Tags: git, github

I have about five local commits. But in the first commit I added big file, about 150MB. When I push to github I get error about big file.

I have tried to delete this file in the last commit, but it doesnt't work. I thought that git may be understand it, but it isn't.

How can I delete this file from commit or delete the first commit entirely if it easy?

Comment: You can use `git rebase`.

Comment: 'Interactive rebase' explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository should help you.

Comment: Use the "edit" option of interactive rebasing as mentioned above, and you can stop, remove the file, then continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Interactive rebase' part of the answer in

[How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

should help you.

The 'git lola' command there is an alias for 'git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all --date=local'

Comment: Not sure of the `lola` command's relevance, but you should provide an example of how to rebase in case that link goes away.

Comment: I linked to a stackoverflow answer hoping that it would remain available (practically) indefinitely. Is there some kind of expiration for old answers?

Comment: I didn't check the target- no worries :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the head and then unstage the 150 mb file and delete, and commit again like this:

> - 1st - `git reset --soft HEAD~1`
> - 2nd - `git reset -q HEAD -- <FILE>`
> - 3rd - delete file
> - **So now just add and commit other files**

Comment: Will I loose history?

Comment: @user348173 nop, you will just lose the history from the 150 mb file

Comment: Actually, you *will* lose your commit history as you're undoing the commits to the point where you introduce the big file. Five commits will become one.

Comment: @RobbieAverill you are right, but if it was  the last commit and dont is into remote yet, doesnt have problem,

Answer (score 0):

You can use git log to display commit history, and then use git reset SHA, where SHA is the first 7 characters of a previous commit, to put that as your most recent commit

```
1 - git log
2 - git reset SHA
```